# Simple C++ module system is not working correctly

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries

I have implemented in C++ a simple module system (for demonstrative purpose only). Unfortunately the program is not working correctly (it produces not the expected output, it prints nothing out).

Here is my source code:

**module.hpp**

```
#ifndef _MODULE_HPP
#define _MODULE_HPP

#include <memory>

/// Interface for modules.
class Module {
  public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
    virtual ~Module(){};
};

/// Symbol of the module construtor function.
const auto MODULE_CONSTRUCTOR_SYMBOL = "create_module";

/// Type of the module constructor function.
using MODULE_CONSTRUCTOR = std::unique_ptr<Module> (*)();

#endif /* _MODULE_HPP */
```

**first.hpp**

```
#ifndef _FIRST_HPP
#define _FIRST_HPP

#include <iostream>

#include "module.hpp"

class First : public Module
{

public:

    First();

    virtual ~First();

    virtual void run();

    std::unique_ptr<Module> create_module(void);

};

extern "C"
{
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Module> create_first_module_t(void);

    std::unique_ptr<Module> create_module(void);
}

#endif /* _FIRST_HPP */
```

**first.cpp**

```
#include "first.hpp"

First::First()
{
}

std::unique_ptr<Module> First::create_module()
{
    auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<Module>{};

    std::cout << "Creation of first module" << std::endl;

    return ptr;
}

First::~First()
{
    std::cout << "Destruction of first module" << std::endl;
}

void First::run()
{
    std::cout << "Running the first module" << std::endl;
}
```

**second.hpp**

```
#ifndef _SECOND_HPP
#define _SECOND_HPP

#include <iostream>

#include "module.hpp"

class Second : public Module
{

public:

    Second();

    virtual ~Second();

    virtual void run();

    std::unique_ptr<Module> create_module(void);

};

extern "C"
{
    typedef std::unique_ptr<Module> create_second_module_t(void);

    std::unique_ptr<Module> create_module(void);
}

#endif /* _SECOND_HPP */
```

**second.cpp**

```
#include "second.hpp"

Second::Second()
{
}

std::unique_ptr<Module> Second::create_module()
{
    auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<Module>{};

    std::cout << "Creation of second module" << std::endl;

    return ptr;
}

Second::~Second()
{
    std::cout << "Destruction of second module" << std::endl;
}

void Second::run()
{
    std::cout << "Running the second module" << std::endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <memory>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#include "first.hpp"
#include "second.hpp"

int main(void)
{
    if (void* firstModule = dlopen("libFirst", RTLD_NOW))
    {
        if (create_first_module_t* createFirstModule = (create_first_module_t*)dlsym(firstModule, "create_module"))
        {
            std::unique_ptr<Module> firstModule(createFirstModule());
            firstModule.get()->run();
        }

        dlclose(firstModule);
    }

    if (void* secondModule = dlopen("libSecond", RTLD_NOW))
    {
        if (create_second_module_t* createSecondModule = (create_second_module_t*)dlsym(secondModule, "create_module"))
        {
            std::unique_ptr<Module> secondModule(createSecondModule());
            secondModule.get()->run();
        }

        dlclose(secondModule);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the instructions for the g++ compiler (on a linux machine):

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -shared -fPIC first.cpp -o first.so -ldl
g++ -Wall -Wextra -shared -fPIC second.cpp -o second.so -ldl
g++ -Wall -Wextra -c main.cpp
g++ -o main main.o first.so -ldl
```

The expected output should be the following:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main ./first.so
Creation of first module
Running the first module
Destruction of first module

$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main ./first.so ./second.so
Creation of first module
Creation of second module
Running the first module
Running the second module
Destruction of first module
Destruction of second module
```

Something is wrong with my implementation, but I do not know where the mistakes are.

I hope that someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: Have you attempted to debug this?  Or generate a [mcve]?  Or, as evidenced above, simply write until it compiled, then noticed it didn't work on the first try, and asked a question about "fix my code"?

Comment: You don't accept arguments (`main(void)` which is C-ish BTW) but you expect that giving arguments will change the behavior of your program.  You are trying to load libraries `libFirst`, `libSecond` but you create libraries `first.so` and `second.so`.  That's for the obvious mistakes which hint that you are a little too much out of your depth.  I'd suggest starting by the basics.